# Session setting expiring for VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, session

In Sales Force Service Cloud the session is set to expire 15 min.

However the session does not expiring after 15 min, and no time-out pop-up screen appears, but directs to the Dashboard when we click the button.

If a user doesn't do anything for more than 15 minutes he is facing this 
particular error without any popup message. Going further when I checked the
 sessions activity in the Org there is a VF page session which expires after 15 
minutes that is fine if user didn't open or click elsewhere still the popup
 needs to be appear and why the UI session and VF session is different.